# How can I "interconnect" two sockets in Linux?

Tags: linux, networking, sockets

There are two connected sockets. How can I interconnect them?

1. Data appeared on the one socket should be written to the other.
2. EOF/FIN should propogate well. If one is half-closed, the other should also be half-closed.

```
int client = get_connected_client_socket();
int proxy = get_connected_proxy_socket();
negotiate_with_proxy(proxy);
iterconnect(client, proxy); 
// Now forgot about both client and proxy. 
// System should handle IO/shutdown/close. 
// Ideally even without any support of the user-space process.
```

Can Linux do it? Can it be done by tricking connection tracking to change tracking status of existing connection?

@related [Determine how much can I write into a filehandle; copying data from one FH to the other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2673975/determine-how-much-can-i-write-into-a-filehandle-copying-data-from-one-fh-to-the)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you aware of [splice()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/splice).  Based on your two questions I *think* this is where you are headed.  Last I checked you can't do this in one splice call because both of file descriptors can't be sockets.  But you should be able to do it in 2 calls (sockin->pipe->sockout).  Also take a look at [tee()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/tee).  These may not be exactly what you want but from what I can figure they are in the ballpark.

Comment: No, I wasn't aware of `splice` (I only theoretically knew about `sendfile`). I'll think and test it.

Comment: @Vi.: I guess you were using TCP sockets ? It seems this approach won't work for UDP sockets ?

Comment: I'm not sure about UDP. If you know good approach (especially if it does not require process being still available for sockets to be still connected), you can tell it.

Answer (score 3):

You will need a userspace process to hang around and do the copying of data from one socket to the other.  It's pretty simple though:

- Any data `read` from socket A, `write` to socket B;
- Any data `read` from socket B, `write` to socket A;
- If `read` returns 0 on socket A, call `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` on socket B;
- If `read` returns 0 on socket B, call `shutdown(SHUT_WR)` on socket A;
- Once both sockets have returned 0 from read, `close` both sockets and exit;
- If either socket returns `EPIPE`, `close` both sockets and exit.

As [Newton Falls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677262/how-can-i-interconnect-two-sockets-in-linux/2678110#2678110) mentions, you can use `splice()` to do this in a zero-copy manner, but that's just a performance enhancement; get it working with `read`/`write` first.  You should be able to just `fork()` off a child to do this, which will make it "fire and forget" for your main process.

Comment: Looks like `splice` is the thing can help. `write` is not good, because it can write less then I requested and I must save the rest somewhere. `fork` is not good, because of new connection => new process, also it needs careful handling of FDs (inherited/non-inherited).

Comment: As I said, `splice()` is just a performance enhancement - it too can splice less than you requested, and it won't make `fork()` any more or less useful (you still have to keep `splice()`ing until the connection is finished).

Comment: If splice spliced less than I requested, the rest (`size_I_requested - size_actually_spliced`) will remain in a read FD, so I can splice it later when output will unblock without storing the data in my process. So pipe buffer will be used and I don't need to allocate/deallocate things in my program.

Comment: With `read`/`write` it remains in the buffer that you did the `read` into (which would typically be a stack-allocated local).

Answer (score 0):

A unix domain socket may help. See the man page:

```
man unix
```

Comment: Not found anything useful in `man 7 unix`. I want my sockets to gain similar inter-influence as `socketpair` sockets have.

I expect that `interconnect` to work with TCP, UNIX sockets and file descriptors.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the socat tool. That's the best tool to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: I know and use it often. But the question is about how to do it in the program. Spawning `socat - -` for this is is too wasteful.